# React. Component declaration using fat arrow function (ES6 syntax specification)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Learning React I've come across two ways of declaring.

Using *classic* `fat arrow` syntax with `return` statement.

```
const Component = () => {
  return (
      <div>Hello</div>
  )
}
```

And recently I've discoverd simplified version.

```
const Component = () => (
  <div>Hello</div>
)
```

I wasn't able to find explanation why the 2nd method works, so maybe you can share some experience on this topic or even leave an article link that covers it more?

Comment: See [arrow functions on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: Fat arrow acts as an implicit return. So the first is redundant.

Comment: Because arrow functions have many defined syntaxes. The first creates a block for a function that has more than one statement or expression. The latter does not create a block and implicitly returns the expression.

Comment: @MartinMazzaDawson, that is not correct.  The fat arrow does not act as an implicit return.  It only acts as an implicit return if the `{` `}` brackets are omitted.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah Quite right. I forgot about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A arrow function with a single expression not surrounded by curly braces as its body is returned

```
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression
// equivalent to: (param1, param2, …, paramN) => { return expression; }
```

source: [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 1):

- if in a arrow function only single element is written then it by default return that expression . there is no need to write curly braces or return keyword.
- if more than one element are present than applying curly braces and return keyword is necessary.

```js
cont component=()=>(
        <div>
          <div>hello</div>
          <p>How are you</p>
        </div>
          )
```

- In above case top level div encapsulate all so it is consider as one element. thats why above called will run perfectly fine , returning a jsx element